# Why is the text stretching in a Text Field in a Split View?

Tags: cocoa, stretch

When I adjust the size of the text field using a divider, if the text is not selected it stretches like [this](http://kttns.org/mmy5n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text field ordinarily only holds a single line of text at a time; you wouldn't make it vertically sizable. Perhaps you want a [text view](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead?

Comment: I'm using core data and it won't display the text string in a Text View but it will in a text field any idea what to do?

Comment: Fixed It! You needed to use a Wrapping Text Field.